# Pandas Dataseries get values by level

Tags: python, pandas

I am dealing with pandas series like the following

> x=pd.Series([1, 2, 1, 4, 2, 6, 7, 8, 1, 1], index=['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'])

The indices are non unique, but will always map to the same value, for example 'a' always corresponds to '1' in my sample, b always maps to '2' etc. So if I want to see which values correspond to each index value I simply need to write

```
x.mean(level=0)
a    1
b    2
c    4
d    6
e    7
f    8
g    1
dtype: int64
```

The difficulty arises when the values are strings, I can't call 'mean()' on strings but I would still like to return a similar list in this case. Any ideas on a good way to do that?

> x=pd.Series(['1', '2', '1', '4', '2', '6', '7', '8', '1', '1'], index=['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'g'])

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So long as your indices map directly to the values then you can simply call `drop_duplicates`:

```
In [83]:

x.drop_duplicates()
Out[83]:
a    1
b    2
c    4
d    6
e    7
f    8
dtype: int64
```

example:

```
In [86]:

x = pd.Series(['XX', 'hello', 'XX', '4', 'hello', '6', '7', '8'], index=['a', 'b', 'a', 'c', 'b', 'd', 'e', 'f'])
x
Out[86]:
a       XX
b    hello
a       XX
c        4
b    hello
d        6
e        7
f        8
dtype: object
In [87]:

x.drop_duplicates()
Out[87]:
a       XX
b    hello
c        4
d        6
e        7
f        8
dtype: object
```

**EDIT** a roundabout method would be to reset the index so that the index values are a new column, drop duplicates and then set the index back again:

```
In [100]:

x.reset_index().drop_duplicates().set_index('index')
Out[100]:
       0
index   
a      1
b      2
c      4
d      6
e      7
f      8
g      1
```

Comment: This works as long as any other index is not mapped to XX, I modified my question to reflect this

Answer (score 1):

`pandas.Series.values` are numpy `ndarray`s. Perhaps doing a `values.astype(int)` would solve your problem?

Comment: my strings are not convertible to ints, this is a simplified example

Answer (score 1):

You can also ensure that you're getting all of the unique indices without reshaping the array by getting a list of the unique index values and plugging that back into the index using `iloc`. Numpy's `unique` method includes a `return_index` arg which provides a tuple of `(unique_values, indices)`:

```
In [3]: x.iloc[np.unique(x.index.values, return_index=True)[1]]
Out[3]:
a    1
b    2
c    4
d    6
e    7
f    8
g    1
dtype: int64
```